# Jenkins groovy MissingMethodException No signature of method

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-shared-libraries

I am facing

> getThingsDone() is applicable for argument types: () values: []

error for code as below,

```
in shared library ....
vars/pipeline.groovy

def getThingsDone(m = null){
   echo "done"
}

in some project that includes shared library

@Library(shared_pipeline@branch_name) _
pipeline.getThingsDone()
```

I tried with defining getThingsDone(...)

- without any arguments
- with string arguments
- with Map arguments

Nothing works. So I want to get a function that accepts no parameter(s) up and running. But it breaks up with the entire stack trace as below,

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.getThingsDone() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:58)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:64)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:54)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:155)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:133)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:120)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:153)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:157)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:7)
at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:57)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(FunctionCallBlock.java:77)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor208.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:122)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:261)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:19)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:35)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:32)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:32)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:174)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:331)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$100(CpsThreadGroup.java:82)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:243)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:231)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Tried on my local Jenkins. It would not let me use `pipeline` as script name, that gave me a 'not permitted' exception. When I use something else like `customPipeline.getThingsDone()` everything works as expected. Try using a different name as `pipeline` might interfer with the global `pipeline` step for the declarative pipeline. If it doesn't help you should update Jenkins and/or your pipeline plugins.

Comment: it did allow me to have pipeline script name. no issues with that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***global variables need to accessed from script directive***

In above case, getThingsDone() is a global function. And according to https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-42360, global variables/functions are not allowed to be used outside of script directive.

Comment: Your sample code actually didn‘t look like you were using declarative pipeline. In scripted pipeline you won’t need any extra script block.

Answer (score 3):

**The Problem**: you configured an external Jenkins shared library that contains some functions you want to use in your jenkins pipeline. However, your Jenkins doesn't recognize the method signature and throws an exception.

**issue**:

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: 
No signature of method: java.lang.Class.someMethodName()
```

**Solution**:

the relations between the to would be like:

```
<shared library> contains: <some function> -> jenkins imports this function and can use it.
```

1. validate the function name doesn't have **Typo or Missing Characters**, validate that the input arguments in the right order.
2. You need to verify that the **library is imported correctly**.

   ```
   @Library('my-shared-library') _

   /* Using a version specifier, such as branch, tag, etc */
   @Library('my-shared-library@1.0') _

   /*Accessing multiple libraries with one statement */
   @Library(['my-shared-library', 'otherlib@abc1234']) _
   ```
3. The **global function should be wrapped in script directive**, for example the file name: `startServer.groovy`

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env groovy

   def call() {
       script{
           sh """#!/bin/bash -le
               cd ${workspace}/app
               npm start
           """
       }
   }
   ```

[on jenkins pipeline:]

```
 //pipeline code...
  startServer()
```

4. If you declare a **static function inside a groovy** class, make sure that the class is starting with lowercase letter. for example use: `nodeUtils.groovy` and NOT `Nodeutils.groovy` (it's for some reason unrecognized)

   ```
    #!/usr/bin/env groovy

       def startServer() {
           script{
               sh """#!/bin/bash -le
                   cd ${workspace}/app
                   npm start
               """
           }
       }

       def installPackages() {
           script{
               sh """#!/bin/bash -le
                   cd ${workspace}/app
                   npm install --save-dev
               """
           }
       }
   ```

[on jenkins pipeline:]

```
//pipeline code...
nodeUtils.installPackages()
```

Comment: Point "4." was the helping info for me - I've had the filename starting with a capital letter. That was no problem when importing the library with
"library identifier: 'my-shared-library@master', retriever: modernSCM(....)"
but was a problem when importing a global library with
"@Library('my-shared-library') _" - the issue you mentioned (No signature of method: java.lang.Class.someMethodName()) came up.