# No signature of method: collectLogs.call() is applicable for argument types

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

**Hi
I tried to run my groovy script that collect a log from appended files**

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
import static groovy.io.FileType.FILES
def call() {
    def CURRENT_DIRECTORY_PATH = 'automation-system-tests/ansible/appli'
    def ZIP_NAME = 'appLogs.zip'
    def FULL_LOGS_PATH = new File("/var/log/full.log")
    def LOG_LIST = []

new File("/var/log/").traverse(type: groovy.io.FileType.FILES, nameFilter: ~/app.*.log/) { next ->
     LOG_LIST << next
      }
 LOG_LIST.each{ FULL_LOGS_PATH.append(it.text) }

    echo 'Collecting Logs from the machine'
    collectLogs(FULL_LOGS_PATH, ZIP_NAME)
    archiveArtifacts artifacts: "${CURRENT_DIRECTORY_PATH}/machineLogs/**/*", allowEmptyArchive: true
}
```

**i got this error**

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: collectLogs.call() is applicable for argument types: (java.io.File, java.lang.String) values: [/var/log/full.log, appLogs.zip]
Possible solutions: call(java.lang.String, java.lang.String), wait(), any(), run(), run(), collect()
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:58)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:20)
    at collectPublishLogs.call(collectPublishLogs.groovy:23)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:269)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:86)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor210.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.LocalVariableBlock$LocalVariable.get(LocalVariableBlock.java:39)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.LocalVariableBlock.evalLValue(LocalVariableBlock.java:28)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$BlockImpl.eval(LValueBlock.java:55)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock.eval(LValueBlock.java:16)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:185)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:400)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:96)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:312)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:276)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:136)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

**Is it the same issue or something else can you please advise**
[Jenkins groovy MissingMethodException No signature of method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51412317/jenkins-groovy-missingmethodexception-no-signature-of-method)

Comment: The signature of your call methods needs to contain the correct parameters, otherwise it wont be found. By the way, you can omit the .call() and just do collectLogs()

Answer (score 2):

The error states:

```
No signature of method: collectLogs.call() is applicable for argument types: (java.io.File, java.lang.String) values: [/var/log/full.log, appLogs.zip]
                                                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Possible solutions: call(java.lang.String, java.lang.String), wait(), any(), run(), run(), collect()
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

As suggested, the first argument must not be `File` but `String`.  E.g.
use:

```
collectLogs(FULL_LOGS_PATH.toString(), ZIP_NAME)
```

Or just use a string directly for your variable if the other places
allow for that.